Azure Functions VSCode Extension and Core tools can't deploy to Azure
Initial Issue: Azure Function not showing HTTP Triggers when deployed.
OS: Tried on both macOS M1 and Windows 11.
Repro Steps:
Create a Python project with HTTP Trigger function and open it in VS Code.
Create a Python Linux Consumption function app.
Deploy the Python project to the above function app.
Check whether there is a HTTP Trigger function under the "Functions" node in VSCode or in the Azure Portal.
Expect: There is a HTTP Trigger function under the "Functions" node both in VSCode and Azure Portal.
Actual: There is no function under the "Functions" node both in VSCode and Azure Portal.
But the Function when run locally with Azure Function core tools works fine, with the HTTP Triggers.
Azure Functions tab in VSCode Extension
Azure Portal Screenshot of the Function App having no triggers
I tried to redeploy to the Function App using the following command:
func azure functionapp publish
And got this error:
[2024-08-13T15:42:56.351Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Remote build is a new feature added to function apps.
Your function app cloud-project-api does not support remote build as it was created before August 1st, 2019.
Please use '--build local' or '--build-native-deps'.
For more information, please visit https://aka.ms/remotebuild

Even though this function app was created few minutes ago.
I have tried both, the Azure Functions VSCode Extension and Azure Functions Core tools to deploy the locally developer function to Azure, but no triggers show up. Even though the Function App works locally, using the Azure Functions Core Tools.
Local run
Azure Functions Core Tools                                                                                                                                      
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-13T15:19:05.679Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpTrigger:  http://localhost:7071/api/project_http

        http_trigger:  http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger


Are you using default http trigger function code or your own code? Please provide your function code, requirements.txt and local.settings.json.

One thing I started doing semi-recently is putting all my functions on github and then using github actions to deploy. Here's the MS doc on it.

Make sure you have the setting "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing" in local.settings.json.
local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}

Ensure the function signature is correct in both the http triggers:
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
// Existing code 
    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

@app.route(route="HttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def HttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

// Existing code 

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )


Make sure the modules in requirements.txt are not causing the issue.

I have created a python function with two http triggers and deployed to Azure.

Using VSCode:



Using function core tools command func azure functionapp publish <functionappname>

C:\Users\uname\pyfn>func azure functionapp publish kpyfn14

Getting site publishing info...
[2024-08-14T07:50:30.309Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING app setting.
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app setting.
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Uploading 1.18 KB [###############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '803c4630-2'.
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot

// Removed few logs

Number of gids 1
        root (0)
Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-kpyfn14.zip located
Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
Resetting all workers for kpyfn14.azurewebsites.net
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
[2024-08-14T07:51:20.446Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in kpyfn14:
    HttpTrigger - [httpTrigger]
        Invoke url: https://kpyfn14.azurewebsites.net/api/httptrigger

    http_trigger - [httpTrigger]
        Invoke url: https://kpyfn14.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger

Portal:

